# Advantages and Disadvantages of Using Ajax on public page

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, jquery

I want to make a project like the Symptoms checker like WebMD did it 
[WebMD Symptom Checker](http://symptoms.webmd.com/default.htm#./introView) 
 i want not logged in user to interact with it.

I dont want to make it in FLASH like webmd did it, i want to make it using JQuery and Ajax,

What is the Advantages and Disadvantages of doing a project like this using Jquery and Ajax , well, i will be implementing it using Zend framework

Does Ajax Requests on a Project like this and its on a public page affect on website security ? Does it affect on SEO ? What the disadvantage for using Ajax on this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know what you mean exactly by advantages and disadvantages but I think you mean that you want it implemented in HTML5 instead of Flash.

**Flash strengths:**

- Flash is more ubiquitous (most of desktop users).
- The Flash developer community is large and mature.
- The developer tools are strong and well supported.
- Designers are more comfortable in working in flash.
- The 2D and 3D APIs are more mature and usable than Canvas.
- Flash gives you better access to web cam and and audio recording.
- Flash better supports streaming, secure and live
  video.

**Flash weaknesses:**

- Information embedded in Flash is often invisible to search engines.
- Website reporting on Flash navigation is problematic and cumbersome.
- Flash breaks web usability standards.
- Lack of consistent cross platform support (not all devices have the same version installed).
- Code embedding Flash objects doesn’t pass w3c validation.
- Some users disable Flash to avoid flash based advertising.
- Website updates continually require Flash skills.
- Flash breaks Search Engine Site Previews.
- Flash doesn’t work well with Mac OSX, and Apple’s mobile devices do
  not support Flash content.

**HTML5 strengths:**

- Better suited for mobile devices (lower battery consumption).
- HTML5 uses DOM and HTML support, so plug-ins and 3rd party programs
  are unnecessary for video and audio embedding.
- Websites with HTML5 elements have greater consistency in terms of the
  HTML used to code a page on one site compared to another.
- More descriptive semantics
- Richer Media Elements
- HTML5 is the future.

**HTML5 weaknesses**

- Only modern browsers support it.
- The language itself is considered a work in progress
- Rich media has to be compressed in multiple formats in order to be
  compatible with most browsers.
- You have to work with JavaScript

Of course you will find many libraries to aid you will using html5. There are great libraries out there other than JQuery such as  [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/)

The only problem I think that Zend framework might cause will working with HTML5 is that it still doesn't support the new HTML5 inputs.

**UPDATE:**

AJAX has no difference when it comes to security than the normal http request. Almost all security risks that can be expoited through normal http requests can be done using AJAX, so the ways to mitigate these vulnerabilities are the same.

As a general rule, search engines do not crawl content generated by JavaScript or Ajax. The most notable exception being Google's crawlable Ajax. But that only applies to Google and even then that's [a bad idea.](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs)

To make your game more search engine friendly you will need to make content available via static links. Without these you essentially have a one page website which is very difficult to rank well. **But** it *can* if you obtain enough incoming links which is possible if your game is very good.

Comment: thanks alot for this, really helps, but the main question for me Is : Does Ajax Requests on a Project like this and its on a public page affect on website security ? Does it affect on SEO  ? What the disadvantage for using Ajax on this project

Comment: Shokran, thats is good. what do you think of doing this application in HTML5 not in flash ?

Comment: you are welcome. I'm not gonna lie to you, but my experience in making HTML5 applications is limited. However, as I said before " HTML5 is the future ". It all depends on your skills and your purpose of making the website. If you need a fast solution Flash is obviously the answer since it is still ahead on HTML5. If you want to target Apple products (iPhone,iPad,...etc.) then HTML5 is the answer. JavaScript is harder to work with, but it's natively supported in the browser. If I were you I would google "Flash vs HTML5 apps" and see the limitations of each of them ;)